# Show that $f(z)=z+a_2 z^2$ is univalent in $\mathbb{D}=\{z∈\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ if and only if $|a_2 | \leq 1/2.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that f(z)=z+a_2 z^2 is univalent in D={z∈C:|z|<1} if and only if |a_2 |≤1/2.
My solution:
(If part): Suppose f(z)=z+a_2 z^2 is univalent in D. By definition, we know that f(z_1 )=f(z_2 ) implies z_1=z_2 (z_1,z_2∈D). 
f(z_1 )=f(z_2 )
z_1+a_2 〖z_1〗^2=z_2+a_2 〖z_2〗^2
(z_1-z_2 )(1+a_2 (z_1+z_2 ))=0
We know that z_1=z_2 implies z_1-z_2=0 . 
This means (1+a_2 (z_1+z_2 ))≠0.
a_2≠(-1)/(2z_2 )
|a_2 |≠|(-1)/(2z_2 )|=1/(2〖|z〗_2 |)>1/2
Therefore, |a_2 |≤1/2.
Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).
[spam]And for some reasons I see here Koebe 1/4 theorem and her applications.[/spam]

Comment: Why the subindex for the parameter $\;a_2\;$ ??

Comment: @DonAntonio I can't say for sure, but $f \in \mathcal{S}$ where $S$ is class of all univalent holomorphic function $g$ on unit disc with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$, and if we use Taylor theorem we obtain  $g(z)=z+a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3+ \cdots$ (and here $a_k=0$ for $k \geq 3$). Maybe, but who knows...Probably OP.

Comment: Thanks @Cortizol, that seems logical.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

$$z+az^2=w+aw^2\;,\;\;z,w\in D\implies(z-w)\left(1+a(z+w)\right)=0$$

Now, if $\;z\neq w\;$ then

$$a=-\frac1{z+w}=-\frac{\overline z+\overline w}{|z+w|^2}\implies |a|=\left|\frac{\overline z+\overline w}{|z+w|^2}\right|=\frac1{|z+w|}\ge\frac12$$

and we get that if the function is *not* univalent then $\;|a|\ge\frac12\;$.